# How can i get the path configured for the current executing httphandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

Consider an HttpHandler that can be configured for multiple paths.
But based on the path that matched a url i could be able to select the settings to apply.

I don't want to pass parameters in the url.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time right now to write a complete example, but I guess this would be the way to go:

- Read Web.config;
- Get locations;
- Loop through locations;
- If location uri matches the current uri (get it from System.Web.HttpContext.Current), then you have the current path;
- Use the current path to retrieve settings from wherever you stored them.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks. I have done that and it works well. I also made use of the reflector tool to see how the handler mapping match is made. There seems to be another challenge i have come across. There different ways to configure httphandlers depending on the type of application pool. Is there a general way to get configuration data of the current pool httphandlers?